# Compare three columns in a SQL table to get middle value

Tags: sql

I need to display the middle value of three columns in a sql table.

eg: For data

```
col1    col2    col3
759     736     773
```

Then output should be `759`.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=153004

Comment: Use conditional experssions eg `CASE`.

Comment: Which RDBMS? eg MySql?

Comment: Those look like credit scores and from my experience I know that you might not always have all three. Can any of them be null?

Answer (score 5):

For Oracle, MySql and Postgres:

```
select col1 + col2 + col3 - greatest(col1, col2, col3) - least(col1, col2, col3)
```

Comment: Assuming the RDBMS is MySql, that's pretty clever

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables thx :) Just realised oracle and postgres have these functions too. As usual, it's SQL Server trailing the pack

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case` expression (cases when col[n] can be equal are not covered - instructions unclear):

```
select case 
       when (col1 > col2 and col2 > col3) or (col3 > col2 and col2 > col1) then col2 
       when (col1 > col3 and col3 > col2) or (col2 > col3 and col3 > col1) then col3 
       when (col3 > col1 and col1 > col2) or (col2 > col1 and col1 > col3) then col1 
       end
from tbl
```

**Edit**

Taking in consideration new conditions, provided by the *OP*:

1. Any two or all three columns values can be equal.
2. Any two or all three columns can be empty. Can you please tell me how to handle these cases.

```sql
select case 
       when col2 is not null and
            ((col1 is null and col3 is null) or 
             (col3 is null and col1 >= col2) or 
             (col1 is null and col3 >= col2) or 
             (col1 > col2 and col2 >= col3) or 
             (col3 > col2 and col2 >= col1)) then col2 
       when col3 is not null and 
            ((col1 is null and col2 is null) or
             (col2 is null and col1 >= col3) or 
             (col1 is null and col2 >= col3) or 
             (col1 > col3 and col3 >= col2) or 
             (col2 > col3 and col3 >= col1)) then col3 
       when col1 is not null and 
            ((col2 is null and col3 is null) or
             (col2 is null and col3 >= col1) or 
             (col3 is null and col2 >= col1) or 
             (col3 > col1 and col1 >= col2) or 
             (col2 > col1 and col1 >= col3)) then col1 
       else 0
       end
from tbl
```

Comment: 1) Any two or all three columns values can be equal. 2) Any two or all three columns can be empty. Can you please tell me how to handle these cases. Thanks.

Comment: @user28455: Updated. Have not tested, expression gives the lowest values in case one out of three values is `null`.

Comment: @user28455 : By the way, update your question with the RDBMS you are using (and maybe even the version)(add the following _tag(s)_).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres, depending on performance needs, a very nice way to solve problems like this is by using a language extension. I'm familiar with Python, which is a much nicer language for expressing this sort of calculation than plain SQL, so I might do something like this (after making sure that the `plpythonu` language extension is installed):

```
ely=# create or replace function getmid (a integer, b integer, c integer)
returns integer
as $$
if (a is None) or (b is None) or (c is None):
    return None
return sorted([a, b, c])[1]
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

I don't have any good toy data to show the calculation on three integer columns from the same table, but using some toy tables, you can see the function being used like so:

```
ely=# select getmid(a.actor_id, b.movie_id, 3) 
      from actors a 
      join movies_actors b 
      on a.actor_id = b.actor_id
      limit 15;
```

which outputs

```
 getmid 
--------
      3
      3
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
      9
     10
     11
     12
     13
     14
     15
(15 rows)
```

One of the huge benefits is that you can write the Python function to generalize over the number of columns, whereas writing this as a stored procedure is a bit more painful and manually expanding the huge set of case statements as the number of columns grows is extremely impractical.

Similar functionality may exist in other dialects of SQL -- I can only attest to how it works with Postgres.

Comment: Or [even easier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29901878/256196) (without inventing a new wheel)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for SQL Server. The same idea will work on other platforms. (Assumes values are non-null.)

```
declare @a int = 10;
declare @b int = 214;
declare @c int = 131;

select @a + @b + @c
  - (((@a + @b - abs(@a-@b)) / 2.0) + @c - abs(((@a + @b - abs(@a-@b)) / 2.0) - @c)) / 2.0
  - (((@a + @b + abs(@a-@b)) / 2.0) + @c + abs(((@a + @b + abs(@a-@b)) / 2.0) - @c)) / 2.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure sure about this; setting `@a` to 216 also returns 131, instead of 214

Comment: Yeah, it is sensitive to the order of the numbers after all. I thought I tested with enough combinations.

Comment: My mistake was easy to fix but it's still really only useful it you don't have a `greatest/least` available and for some reason you hate `case` expressions.